# How to select json data to display in html

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

I have this json data URL and i want to select only France data to display in html but i don't know how to do. please help me to do that

https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries

This is my JAVASCRIPT

```
// API Fetch Call
 const api_url = './src/india.json';
 async function getCcount() {
     const response = await fetch(api_url);
     const data = await response.json();
     const {
         cases,
         active,
         deaths,
         recovered
     } = data;

     document.getElementById('t-count').textContent = cases;
     document.getElementById('a-count').textContent = active;
     document.getElementById('d-count').textContent = deaths;
     document.getElementById('r-count').textContent = recovered;
 }

 getCcount();
```

How can i select only France data to display in HTML. Using the fetch function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the object in the `data` array that has the `country` property with the value `"France"`, something like the following:

```js
(async() => {
  try {
    const api_url = 'https://coronavirus-19-api.herokuapp.com/countries';
    const response = await fetch(api_url);
    if (response.status !== 200) {
      console.log(`Status Code: ${response.status}`);
      return;
    }
    const data = await response.json();
    const {
      cases,
      active,
      deaths,
      recovered
    } = data.find(covid => covid.country === 'France');

    document.getElementById('t-count').textContent = cases;
    document.getElementById('a-count').textContent = active;
    document.getElementById('d-count').textContent = deaths;
    document.getElementById('r-count').textContent = recovered;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Fetch Error: ${err}`);
  }
})();
```

```html
Cases: <span id='t-count'></span><br/> Active: <span id='a-count'></span><br/> Deaths: <span id='d-count'></span><br/> Recovered: <span id='r-count'></span><br/>
```

> The `find()` method returns the value of the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.